# Detect standalone mode on old chrome version

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

According to [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/display-mode), `display-mode: standalone` only can detect on M48 or newer version. Is there any way to detect the mode on older version?

Comment: No not possible. M46 and newer only, and there is no way to check if display-mode is available with M46 and older.

Answer (score 7):

No this is not possible.
[Check this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode)

> @supports for display-mode is only supported starting with Chrome 48.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not a direct answer but it's offering a workaround.

As much as I understand the article, you can configure your website (in the *manifest.json*) to open with querystring (for example) if it opens from the homescreen. So you can set a flag on the DOM - let's say add class to the `body` tag. In this way you can detect in eitgher css or js if you run in **standalone mode**.

For example:

```js
var isStandalone = false;
if (location.search.indexOf('standalone=true') > -1) {
  isStandalone = true;
  document.body.classList.add('standalone-mode');
}

// from now on you can check if you run in standalone by checking 'isStandalone' param.
```

```css
header {
  background: red;
}

/* this is a style for standalone mode only */
body.standalone header {
  background: green
}
```

Comment: It's a well though work around but I think you would have 'standalone=true' in URL even on Chrome > 48 version.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I'm not sure what id the problem if it's working on Chrome > 48, if it will work for you anyway..

Answer (score 0):

For applications wrapped in electron you might use what is described here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2288

```
window && window.process && window.process.type
```

or

```
navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(' electron/') > -1;
```